# Working with Handlebar.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I was actually trying to find some tutorials on Handlebar.js & I found this http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/05/javascript-templating-handlebars-tutorial

But it is not actually working as expected.

What I am doing is I have an **index.html** file,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Messing with Handlebars</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script id="ajax-comment" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <li>
            <span class="meta">{{name}} on {{date}}</span>
            <p>{{comment}}</p>
            </li>
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

and an **app.js** which contains the code.

```
var source = $("#ajax-comment").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var data = {
    name : "Jack",
    date : "12/04/12",
    comment : "This is a really awesome tutorial. Thanks."
};
$("ul").append(template(data));
```

But all I am getting is a blank page. Any mistake I am making here? Detailed explanations would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"ul"` element doesn't exist, you must append it to something which actually exists.

just add a `<ul></ul>` somewhere in the body.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3U4uh/)

Comment: But still I am getting a blank page, It doesn't even make a difference if am using Chrome or FireFox.

Comment: The fiddle works ok, does it work for you?.. it might be something else on your page?

Comment: The jsFiddle works okay for me. But whenever I try to open the file in browser it shows a blank page only.

Comment: It gives this error on Console, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of null.

Comment: or on Firebug, TypeError: this._input is null.

Comment: I have changed nothing, just exactly did what you suggested.

Comment: are you sure you added the `<ul></ul>` in the body? I get the same error when no `<ul>` is present. But when i add it, everything works.

Comment: Yes, I added the <ul></ul> in the body. I don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613967/why-is-browser-returning-error-typeerror-this-input-is-null-in-firefox-and)
Seems like the jquery function was not able to access the element since the DOM wasnt loaded before the call was made. I tried some more combinations after the initial changes of calling the app.js code(without wrapping it inside a function) only after the DOM was loaded which worked.
For example I moved the script call just before the `</body>` which worked too.

`... <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>`

It also helped me to know whether we use HTML or XHTML as our document type, to understand this problem better.

Answer (score 0):

try putting ref to your external JS at bottom, just above the closing body tag

eg

```
<body>
    <ul></ul>
   <!-- last thing on the page--> 
   <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

this seemed to have solved it for me