# Unable to get the HTML result by executing a Handlebars template with a context

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I have the following code in my javascript:

```
    var context = {
        "title": section_title
    };

    var section_template = $("section-template").html(),
        template = Handlebars.compile(section_template);

    alert("yeah!");
    alert(context.title);
    var final_section_content = template(context);

    alert("WHat?");
```

The `alerts()` are there purely for debugging purposes.

`section_template` is correctly populated with the template that I prepared

`template` has a function as its value so I assume the compilation went well too.

The "yeah!" and the title of the context are displayed correctly. However, something seems to be going wrong in the `template(context);` execution. The "What?" alert is never raised, and thus the HTML content is never set (later in the program). Later in the program, I use the `final_section_content` as the value for the jQuery `before()` function. But the "What?" itself is not being executed. Any idea why?

Template Code:

```
<script id="section-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8 offset1">
            {{! This will contain the section requirements}}
            <div class="section-title">
                <span class="add-on">
                    <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
                </span>

                <h2>
                    {{title}}
                </h2>
                <i class="icon-list" data-placement="bottom" data-title="Create sub-section"></i>
                <i class="icon-pencil" data-placement="bottom" data-title="Edit section title"></i>
                <i class="icon-trash" data-placement="bottom" data-title="Delete section"></i>
                <div class="subsection">
                    {{! Dummy container for subsection}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span2 offset1">
            {{! This will contain the total score for the section}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Comment: Also I find, `console.log` (unless you're in IE) to be much easier to handle than interrupting alerts when trying to debug. Check it out!

Comment: @RyanLynch Yes, you are correct. The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined". Not sure what it means... tkone - Yeah. I guess I will start using that from now instead of alert()

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: @RyanLynch It looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/itBHBnTd)

Comment: @RyanLynch To give some more information, this error is raised in line  431 of the handlebar javascript source file. "this._input.match(...)" is where the error is. _input seems to be empty...

Comment: I've added the template code to your question.  In the future, use this method instead of an external site like pastebin.

Comment: What are the three handlebars in that subsection div?  Is that an escape sequence?

Comment: @RyanLynch I corrected it. It's meant to be a comment. The div container will be populated later. After correcting it, the issue still remains. And a thanks for adding the template code to the question. Will keep it in mind in the future.

Comment: Shouldn't `$("section-template")` be `$("#section-template")`? The error you're seeing usually means that you've done a `Handlebars.compile(null)`.

Comment: Are you doing this before #section-template is loaded?  +1 to @mu is too short's comment as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613967/why-is-browser-returning-error-typeerror-this-input-is-null-in-firefox-and

Comment: @RyanLynch Bingo. That's the cause of the issue! Coincidentally, I also came across that when I googled "this._input"! But this was so difficult to find out. I mean, section_template did have the html, I checked it. The #id seems to have worked without #! Any, can you make that the offical answer. I'll mark it as solved?

Comment: @muistooshort Thank you. In the midst of the chat, I did not realize that a different user has posted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the element containing the template code is loaded prior to querying it's contents using `$('#section-template').html()`.  See [Why is browser returning error "TypeError: this._input is null" in Firefox (and similar in Chrome) when using handlebars.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613967/why-is-browser-returning-error-typeerror-this-input-is-null-in-firefox-and) for more details.

Comment: A +1 to @muistooshort as well.